# parse vector<string> option, in boost program_options

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-program-options

I want to parse my options 
ex) --print-docprop => set default value in vector variable 
    --print-docprop xxx yyy => set "xxx", "yyy" value in vector variable

Tell me how to edit my code

```
vector<string> docpropType_;
po::description options("detail option");
options.add_options()
("print-docprop"
, po::value< std::vector<std::string> >(&docpropType_)->implicit_value(docpropType_,"aaa")
, "print document properties"
)
```

before calling po::store(), I want to set value in docpropType_ variable.
And only use option without next string, I want to default set string, else set given string.

In this code, "--print-docprop" => set "aaa" in docpropType_ 
"--print-docprop xxx yyy"  => set {"xxx", "yyy"} in docpropType_

Comment: You want especially that? Cause your code will work with `--print-docprop xxx --print-docprop yyy`

Comment: I would like to set docpropType_ variable.